# The iPhone could not be restored. An unknown error occurred (9)

Tags: iphone, ios, restore

This is an issue that occurred to my iPhone.

What is the recommended general fix for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by plugging my iPhone into another Windows machine, then placing the iPhone back onto the original machine, then doing a restore on the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error occur today when attempting to update my iPhone 4 to iOS5.  I'm using the latest iTunes (10.5) on Windows 7.  Here's how I resolved it:

1. Disconnected all devices from my computer except the iPhone and rebooted the laptop
2. Put the iPhone in Airplane mode, then cycle the power (power down, power back up)
3. Connect the iPhone and restart the update in iTunes

Answer (score 0):

Re-try again, then run Console for any further details.

For advanced solution try to [Download and install OS X USB Debug Kits](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?q=IOUSB) which will provide more information about USB device and interface detection, driver and interface matching, driver loading and information generated as a result of normal and abnormal conditions.